# Python and Selenium, do I have to get the url multiple times for a change to occur?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I am doing some web scraping and I am going to wait indefinitely on a page until it is available to purchase and my code is the following.

```
def searchPage(input_url):

    currentUrl = input_url
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    driver.get(currentUrl)

    while True:
        try:
            shipIt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-test="shippingBlock"]')
            alertUsers(currentUrl)
            time.sleep(5)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
```

Do I need to do the .get(currentUrl) inside of the while True to constantly get the updated site or will the information update and the condition be met?

Answer (score 0):

If the webpage is updating itself via a javascript (Ajax, whatever...) call,  then you don't need to reload/re-get the page.

***Hint***:
You can check this by opening your webpage in a browser so you can look wether the values/fields are updating automatically without reloading.